# Data compression using images as the code storage medium

Tags: compression, png, qr-code

I have been thinking a lot about data compression and the math around it.  The idea hit me that it might be easier to write the binary equivalent of the file in hex to QR codes saved as PNG file type to compress and then reverse to extract.  I got the idea from all the people taking screen shots of text messages longer than 160 characters and posting to twiter as a means to send longer tweets.

My math goes as follows and my question is where is the flaw in my assumption.

177 x 177 QR code can store 4,296 alphanumeric characters.  PNG QR codes is approximately 870 bytes.  I did 2 tests with PDF files and found that a 158kb PDF file had a binary string of 321,562 characters when converted to hex.  That translates to 75 QR codes which would take 65kb.  When I used Windows10 built in compress tool it compressed to 157kb.

I imagine with OCR you could write the hex code directly to a PNG and then read it back which would be more direct and efficient.  Where is the flaw in this logic for a means of data compression?

EDIT
I put together some code to create an image, PNG file, with the hex representation written in it.  It's hard to tell if all the characters are actually represented.  When I open the image it just shows a portion of the characters and I don't know how to write the hex as wrapped text.

```
public class TextToGraphics {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\file.pdf"));
        try {
            for (int b; (b = is.read()) != -1;) {
                String s = Integer.toHexString(b).toUpperCase();
                if (s.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append('0');
                }
                //sb.append(s).append(' ');
                sb.append(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }        

    System.out.println(sb);

    try {
        int width = 20000, height = 40;

        // TYPE_INT_ARGB specifies the image format: 8-bit RGBA packed
        // into integer pixels
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D ig2 = bi.createGraphics();

        Font font = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 10);
        ig2.setFont(font);
        String message = sb.toString();
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = ig2.getFontMetrics();
        int stringWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(message);
        int stringHeight = fontMetrics.getAscent();
        ig2.setPaint(Color.black);
        ig2.drawString(message, (width - stringWidth) / 2, height / 2 + stringHeight / 4);

        ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("C:\\image.png"));

      } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
      }
```

}

Not sure where I went wrong but so far it looks like my 350kb PDF gets compressed to a 21kb PNG but not sure if I can read all the characters back out to decompress.

Answer (score 3):

Short Version:

PNG and other image compression algorithms are designed to compress images containing 2D patterns, something binary files are unlikely to contain when encoded as an image and as a result would be unlikely to compete with more appropriate compression techniques.

Long Version:

Data compression works by taking advantage of expected patterns in the data being compressed. For example text compression will usually take advantage of repeated runs of characters such as repeated instances of " the " and " a ". Image compression (such as PNG) typically relies on the assumption that pixels near each other will be similar in color.

When a file contains few or no patterns that can be exploited by a particular compression algorithm the file will barely compress or could even become bigger. As an example take a look at [Random Pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjpp8.png).

This is a 200x200 PNG file of random colored pixels. Since there are no patterns in the image it cannot be compressed and as a result the file is larger as a PNG as shown by the following:

```
Raw pixel data size: 200 * 200 * 3(bytes per pixel) = 120 000 bytes

PNG size:            120 304 bytes (304 bytes LARGER)
```

QR codes are typically used to encode text streams such as URLS which are heavily patterned and therefor will compress fairly well, even with an algorithm designed to compress images.

Binary files could contain absolutely anything and so representing them as an image file is likely to produce an image with very few 2D patterns, much like the colored noise image above. When faced with compressing a file who's contents is effectively unknown good approaches are:

Huffman coding:

A technique that takes advantage of an uneven distribution of values in
  the file, eg the letter 'e' being more common than any other in English
  text.

Run-length coding:

A technique that takes advantages of sequences of characters being
  repeated, eg the many occurrences of " the " in this post.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I'm looking to understand whether a picture of binary code would be significantly smaller than the original file itself.  QR codes seem like a convenient and well established way to capture the binary code in an image and read it back again.

I'm looking to understand if this is faulty logic or if it would actually work as a effective/efficient compression algorithm.

Comment: An uncompressed image of a binary file will always be larger than the binary file itself as it will simply contain the exact same data as the binary file stored in a pixels field, with the additional overhead of the image files header data. Compressing the image using PNG or some other image compression technique could potentially make the file smaller but the compression ratio is likely to be low compared to more appropriate techniques as described above.

Comment: If you would like to do some experiments of your own i could write you a simple program that converts a file into a PNG image.

Comment: I put together some code to create an image, PNG file, with the hex representation written in it.  It's hard to tell if all the characters are actually represented.  When I open the image it just shows a portion of the characters and I don't know how to write the hex as wrapped text.

Comment: Ive uploaded a program that converts files too and from PNG here:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/4ck2mg4wsjj12ob/BinToPNG.exe